# Org export: HTML equivalent of '#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.9\textwidth'

Tags: html, css, emacs, latex, org-mode

How can I set the image width of an image exported from org-mode to html to a multiple of the textwidth, i.e. I want the HTML equivalent to the following latex-export option:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.9\textwidth
```

MME:

```
#+CAPTION: Example image
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.9\textwidth
[[file:image.jpg]]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Donec hendrerit tempor tellus.  Donec pretium posuere tellus.  Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus.  Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  Nulla posuere.  Donec vitae dolor.  Nullam tristique diam non turpis.  Cras placerat accumsan nulla.  Nullam rutrum.  Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.
```

Something like `#+ATTR_HTML: :width content` doesn't work.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that is impossible: there is no such thing as textwidth in HTML - you get whatever width the browser window gives you. I suspect what you mean is that whatever the width of the text, you want the image width to be 90% of that - correct? I don't know if that's possible with org attributes, but it should be possible to specify something like this in a CSS file and then ask org to include that CSS file in the HTML output.

Comment: @Nick yes you understand it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to still work, although IIUC the `width` attribute of the `<img>` tag is deprecated (on the HTML side, not the org side):

```
#+CAPTION: Example image
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 90%
[[file:images/img1.png]]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Donec hendrerit tempor tellus.  Donec pretium posuere tellus.  Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus.  Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  Nulla posuere.  Donec vitae dolor.  Nullam tristique diam non turpis.  Cras placerat accumsan nulla.  Nullam rutrum.  Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.
```

And here's one way to do it with CSS:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/image-width.css" />

#+CAPTION: Example image
[[file:images/img1.png]]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Donec hendrerit tempor tellus.  Donec pretium posuere tellus.  Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus.  Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  Nulla posuere.  Donec vitae dolor.  Nullam tristique diam non turpis.  Cras placerat accumsan nulla.  Nullam rutrum.  Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.
```

where the `css/image-width.css` file contains the following:

```
img  { width: 90%; }
```